# Spring MVC + Hibernate Creating an Association Table

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a Registration Entity which holds

- id
- student_id
- course-id
- semester

I have written

- Registration, Course, Student - domain objects
- RegistrationDao, CourseDao, StudentDao
- RegistrationBS, CourseBS, StudentBS

My Registration domain object as follows:

```
class Registration {
    Student student;
    Course course;
    String semester;
}
```

I have a form which consists of two comboboxes (students and courses).

I am posting student_id, course_id, and semester info to the RegistrationController.

Do I need to retrieve student and course objects from their BS? In that case, how can I avoid transaction scope problems?

And, if I use pure SQL, I do not need to retrieve student and courses. Just an insert sql with three given attributes. If I should retrieve these objects, it is a big problem for ORMs, isn't it? Or should I create a named query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to know if you need to retrieve Student and Course objects if you want to persist a Registration using Hibernate. Right?

> Do I need to retrieve student and course objects from their BS?

If you perform a simple session.save(registration), Hibernate is going to make a select and retrieve student/course objects within that given registration.

Unfortunately, Hibernate does not support standard INSERT VALUES via HQL. It only supports INSERT INTO FROM, which is not useful for you.